# Angular JS ng-repeat for table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using the following bootstrap table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Episode Date</th>
         <th>Day</th>
         <th>Projected Cost</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="epi in episodes">
         <td>
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="epi.COST_PRG_EPS_TXN_ID" />
            <label>{{epi.PRG_EPISODE_DATE_DIS | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}} </label>
         </td>
         <td>{{ epi.PRG_EPISODE_DAY }}</td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="epi.COST_PROJECTED" onkeypress="return OnlyNumeric(event);" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="epi.COMMENTS" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

when I use `ng-repeat` for table row (`tr`).

However, when I cut and paste the `ng-repeat` to `tbody`, it works properly.

The requirement is to repeat `tr` and not `tbody` inside the table. How can I do it?

http://i.imgur.com/D52R9lq.png

Comment: Do you remove your `tr`s outside of angular scope?

Comment: It is within the angular scope

Comment: tell us a little more. How do you do it?

Comment: {{episodes}} in table ?Is your table in scope?

Comment: episodes object contains 79 elements. and each element contains a property for COST_PRG_EPS_TXN_ID, PRG_EPISODE_DAY , COST_PROJECTED and COMMENTS. m trying to display these 79 elements

Comment: Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/300/) of your example... it seems to be working fine for me??

Comment: table-striped is a bootstrap class . Can you import the required js/ css also?

Comment: It works properly when the js of table-striped is not applied. But on applying the bootstrap.js of table-striped , it throws an error

Comment: That is incorrect. Bootstrap is for UI improvements only, as you will see in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/301/). Are you absolutely certain that the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` is being caused by this ng-repeat?

Comment: Yes your fiddle is working perfectly, but am still facing the issue. posted the error link.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your html template. Could you provide us with more code (also from your controller) or even reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/clarencedmello/7d3ace5646ea691d117e#file-test-html

Comment: [Here is your code in a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iRZ2id2zbL0Pq1I1YMv4?p=preview) – seems to me to be working ?! Although I do notice you're referencing your `angular` script locally. Have you tried using a different version? In the Plunker I used the following CDN: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js`